# Join beta/sign up as one form

Tags: forms

I have a bit of a problem.

I'm working on an iPhone app landing page and was wondering what would be the best way to combine the "join beta" and "sign up form" as one.

[image]

Btw "Preferred Platform" has the options - Website, iPhone, Android, Windows, Blackberry

Would appreciate any feedback on what I have right now and any wire frame designs.

Comment: You could autopopulate the Enter Email address (once) with the email address from the above form when the sign up button is clicked...if it's an AJAX form submit anyway. That way you keep them on page, but you could also bring them to a second page after that also has the beta program form, with their email filled out (but this might seem 'creepy' if you load a new page and already "know" their email)

Comment: I would go with what Ben says but I am not sure why you need the platform here .If I am not mistaken,this is an iphone app right or do you plan to extend it to other platforms too?

Comment: It's an iPhone app at the moment that will be extended to other platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a single form with just an email field and an optional check box that says "I want in the beta programme!" This keeps the form minimal and unintimidating at first glance, while also reducing the actual complexity. Just make sure to call attention to the opt in option.

When the box is checked, add in the Preferred platform field (simple javascript). This way there's one submit button; put it at the bottom so the user sees the option to opt into the beta as they sign up.

You could even change the "Sign up" button copy to "Request Invite" when the "opt in" checkbox is checked. If you do this make sure the button doesn't change sizes or it could look shoddy.

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks fine so far. I would recommend combining the forms so the user only has to enter their email once. So basically, what you have minus the last email form.